# Could not AOT the assembly Facebook.dll (MT3001)

Tags: xamarin.ios, facebook-ios-sdk

This is a cross post from the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69498/could-not-aot-the-assembly-facebook-dll-mt3001)

I have an app that was deploying without issues to a device through Xamarin Studio. After upgrading to Xamarin Studio 6 I am now having the error:

> MTOUCH: Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly
> '../obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-9.3.2/mtouch-cache/Build/Facebook.dll'
> (MT3001)

I am using the latest `Xamarin.Facebook.iOS` nuget package (4.12.0 as of this writing). I have tried all three Linker behavior with the same result.

Is there anything else I can do?

Here's my system details:

> === Xamarin Studio Enterprise ===
>
> Version 6.0 (build 5174) Installation UUID:
> ff1dab9c-8c79-4fc4-b453-23a7c4df9d80 Runtime: Mono 4.4.0
> (mono-4.4.0-branch-c7-baseline/5995f74) (64-bit) GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh
> theme)
>
> Package version: 404000182
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Not Installed
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 6.1.0.71 (Visual Studio Enterprise) Android SDK:
> /.../Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx Supported Android
> versions:
> 4.0.3 (API level 15)
> 4.4 (API level 19)
> 5.0 (API level 21)
> 5.1 (API level 22)
> 6.0 (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.1.3 SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.1 SDK Build
> Tools Version: 23.0.3
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
> https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Xamarin Android Player ===
>
> Not Installed
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 7.3.1 (10188.1) Build 7D1014
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 9.8.0.323 (Visual Studio Enterprise) Hash: 39ebb77 Branch:
> cycle7 Build date: 2016-06-01 21:23:15-0400
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Not Installed
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 600005174 Git revision:
> 694a75f040b7f2309bc43d4f78a3a6572ca898bf Build date: 2016-06-01
> 17:28:08-04 Xamarin addins: 33f406fa2dcf214012c78cb846585f062b2e1d24
> Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle7-baseline
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.11.5 Darwin xxxxx-MacBook-Pro.local 15.5.0 Darwin Kernel
> Version 15.5.0 Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016
> root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Are you deploying on device or on simulator?

Comment: Device! Check out this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41999

Comment: As a work-around you can try to:
Switch off "Project Options > Build > iOS Build > Enable incremental builds".
Ref: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42139